# Subtracting two variable without using __init__() in Class

Tags: python-3.x

```
class Operation1:
    res1=0

    def sub(self,a,b):
        Operation1.res1=self.a-self.b
        return Operation1.res1

o1=Operation1()
print (o1.sub(3,1))
```

Can you please tell without using `__init__` function, how can i implement this? Currently it is giving error.

Comment: Can you please provide the error? @Rakesh

Answer (score 0):

The class `Operation1` has no variables `a` and `b`. So, you cannot access them using `self.a` and `self.b`. Change them to `a` and `b` respectively

```
class Operation1:
    res1 = 0

    def sub(self, a, b):
        Operation1.res1 = a-b
        return Operation1.res1

o1=Operation1()
print(o1.sub(3,1))
```